# "core-header-panel" doesnt seem to work out-of-the-box

Tags: polymer, web-component

I was trying some `core` polymer elements, and I have been having trouble using `core-header-panel` in [my demo](http://enriquemorenotent.com/demos/webcomponents/core-header-panel/).

I think the toolbar is right, because I managed to do [another demo](http://enriquemorenotent.com/demos/webcomponents/core-toolbar/) where it was working with minimal CSS. But all the demo I found for core-header-panel seems to take most of the layout configuration outside the component (Which kinda seems like the point of the component). Did I misinterpret something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best pattern today is to use the polymer layout attributes.

```
<body fullbleed vertical layout>
  <core-header-panel flex>
```

`vertical layout` makes the body a (vertical) flex-box, and the `flex` attribute on the `core-header-panel` will make it fill the available space. `fullbleed` attribute sets body to fit the viewport.

This is a better pattern in general than using `fit` because flex-boxes are more resilient. You could add a different header or footer to body, and the flex panel will adapt.

Also, using `layout` containers and `flex` children is a pattern you can continue to use in other places in the application.

Answer (score 2):

According to the polymer web site core-header-panel is always needs to have a height set on it explicitly. http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html

Try using the fit attribute (http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html):

```
<core-header-panel fit>
  ....
</core-header-panel>
```