# Does Polymer's core-animated-pages require CSS position absolute?

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use core-animated-pages but I have issues with getting it to display things.

The  element always keeps a height of zero pixel unless I use position: absolute and force its size with top/bottom/left/right or do that for the elements it contains, like in the [examples](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demo.html).

Is that the way it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should chek out the [Layout properties](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html) on the Polymer site.

You can use the `fit` attribute on the `core-animated-pages` element. That will set position to absolute and top/bottom/left/right. However the parent element needs an explicit size and `position:relative`.

An alternative and proably better appraoch is to add the `layout` attribute to the parent element and the `flex` attribute to your `core-animated-pages` to fit it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474826/core-header-panel-doesnt-seem-to-work-out-of-the-box)):

```
<body fullbleed vertical layout>
  <core-animated-pages flex>
```